# Filtering out section entries

Tags: filter, forloop

I'm quite new to Craft CMS and have takeen over an application (using Twig templates).  I'm trying to run a filter but not having much joy so maybe I might get some help!

So, there is a people section (`craft.entries.section('people')`) with over 1000 entries. These are displayed in an HTML table, each row has 3 columns (handled using the `batch()` call). I want to exclude certain entries that match a particular condition.

For example, I want to exclude all 'people' that partially match a list of names (e.g 'xyz', 'zzzz', 'joebloggs')

```
{% for people in craft.entries.section('people').order('title asc').limit(500)|batch(3) %}
```

Is it possible to do a query like this before the loop? Or is it something I need to check on each iteration inside the loop? Doing this might make the `batch()` unusable?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for entries, you can use the [search](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#search) parameter:

```
{% set people = craft.entries
    .section('people')
    .search('*xyz* OR *zzzz*') 
%}
```

Then, you can loop through those people like this:

```
{% for person in people |batch(3) %}
    {{ person.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

By default, [search](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) doesn't do fuzzy search, that's where the *s come in. You can, however, [enable fuzzy search by default](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default).

If you want to limit your search to a field, do:

```
{% craft.entries.search('fieldHandle:xyz OR fieldHandle:zzzz') %}
```

Comment: I understand that .search can be used to include those search parameters, but how would you exclude those search parameters? So you would get all entries that do NOT include xyz, zzzz. Thanks –

Comment: I'm sorry, misread your question. As mentioned on the search page of the Craft docs, I think you can exclude search using the `-`. So I guess that would be `.search('-xyz AND -zzzz')` with fuzzy search enabled, then? Not tested, though.

Comment: Hi Paul, i managed to find a way to do it by implementing the following way craft.entries.section('people').title('and, not *xyz*, not *zzzz*).